# Migrations on SQL Azure

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, azure-sql-database

I have a production SQL Azure database. Is there a way to run Migrations against it **remotely** e.g via Powershell? I don't have access to my development machine at the moment, and through a browser inspection I realized the error below is returned:

> > There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

Normally, I would do:

```
 Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges then Update-Database
```

Note: I want to disable* or run migrations that are already deployed remotely, whichever will be faster. I'll appreciate any help on this.

Comment: use migrate.exe ?

Comment: @ErikEJ I haven't used it before, how can I go about it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618307(v=vs.113).aspx (If you deploy it with you app, you should be able to run it from Kudu)